# BufferedImage getTile(): what is it, how does it differ from getSubimage()

Tags: java, image, raster, bufferedimage, tile

What is `BufferedImage getTile()`? I see that is returns a `Raster` object. Is this another form of an image or graphical object? If so, what advantages / disadvantages are there to using `getTile()` vs using `getSubImage()`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `BufferedImage.getTile(int, int)` method is inherited from the [`RenderedImage` interface](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.desktop/java/awt/image/RenderedImage.html), and allows you to get a specific tile to work on. All tiles in an image have equal, fixed, width/height. Each tile is typically one contiguous block of memory. In contrast, `getSubImage()` allows you to get an arbitrary region from the image, regardless of the backing memory. So the methods are not really interchangeable. They are similar in the way they both return "live" views of the full image.

For a `BufferedImage` instance, however, the `getTile()` method is not very useful, as a `BufferedImage` is implemented as a *single* tile (ie. anything other than `bufferedImage.getTile(0, 0)` will throw an `IndexOutOfBoundsException`). If you know you are operating on a `BufferedImage`, the `getRaster()` method is a better option and will do exactly the same.

Other implementations of `RenderedImage`, however, might contain several tiles, and you would use the various tile-related methods to find the number of tiles in each dimension, the tile sizes etc.